# Python Django ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, smtp, django-errors

When using SMTP from Brevo, it works fine on localhost. However, after deploying the project to PythonAnywhere, I encountered a connection refusal error.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.brevo.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env.str('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env.str('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

I found an article on Brevo ([article](https://stackoverflow.com)) how to check port availability.
After following the steps, I attempted to connect by entering "telnet
smtp-relay.brevo.com 587" but received an error message stating "Trying 1.179.118.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Might it be ```smtp-relay.brevo.com```?

Comment: Yeah, sorrty for the typo

Comment: Well, if it can't find that domain, then there's a DNS issue.

Comment: It found it, but  сonnection refused

Comment: Connection refused means that the connection is blocked. Either you have the wrong port, or the service is not listening or there is a firewall doing the blocking.

Comment: Yeah, but it's weird because brevo is on pythonanywhere's whitelist.

Comment: This has been fixed. Pythonanywhere is not support brevo smtp in the free whitelist, but support the brevo api.

Comment: Yup, and maybe that's worth clarifying for anyone else that hits similar problems -- free accounts on PythonAnywhere can only make outbound HTTP and HTTPS connections, so even if something's on our allowlist, you won't be able to make SMTP connections.